# Box with "title" on the edge with white space around

Tags: framed

Given a `framed` package box (or any other of your choice), how can I make the first line (with only one or two words) float on the border the box with a bit of white space on the left and the right sides?

I'm looking for the following effect:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this using the `tikz` library. I presumed you wanted a fully lined box, but not sure?[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{background rectangle}=[thin,draw=black]
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]

\node[align=justify, text width=\textwidth, inner sep=1em]{
Some sample text here thats in the box
};

\node[xshift=3ex, yshift=-0.7ex, overlay, fill=white, draw=white, above 
right] at (current bounding box.north west) {
\textit{Push}
};

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get an odd effect where the box(es) immediately after the first box are shifted a bit to the right.

Comment: Mmm not sure, I tried putting 2 boxes underneath each other and they are not shifted to the right. Can you provide more details or better an example of what you did?

Comment: I realize that this is an old thread, but it might help to put \noindent right in front of the \begin{tikzpicture}.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version using `tcolorbox` to draw the box and place the title on the edge.

[image]

This is the source code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myframe}[2][]{%
  enhanced,colback=white,colframe=black,coltitle=black,
  sharp corners,boxrule=0.4pt,
  fonttitle=\itshape,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-0.3\baselineskip-0.4pt,xshift=2mm},
  boxed title style={tile,size=minimal,left=0.5mm,right=0.5mm,
    colback=white,before upper=\strut},
  title=#2,#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframe}{Push}
  Some sample text here thats in the box.
\end{myframe}

\begin{myframe}{Pop}
  Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text.
  Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text.
  Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text. Some sample text.
\end{myframe}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very cool and intuitive!